# Cursed Item Transfer

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, curses, attunement

Scenario:

Party obtains a cursed weapon.
Player A willfully attunes to Item and doesn't use it, in hopes of avoiding Player B using it, as Player A doesn't trust Player B's motives.
Player B steals the weapon and performs a rest with it.

According to DMG Pg.138:

> A creature's attunement to an item ends if the creature no longer satisfies the Prerequisites for attunement, if the item has been more than 100 feet away for at least 24 hours, if the creature dies, or if another creature attunes to the item. A creature can also voluntarily end attunement by spending another Short Rest focused on the item, unless the item is cursed.

This implies that anyone can attune to an already attuned item and break the previous attunement. With normal items at least... The predicate of the last sentence is about the voluntary de-attunement from Player A, not Player B overtaking the attunement.

DMG Pg. 139:

> Attunement to a cursed item can't be ended voluntarily unless the curse is broken 1st such as with the Remove Curse spell

I guess the main point of contention here is whether the "if another creature attunes to the item" line means a voluntary or involuntary action on behalf of Player A...

Thoughts? Experiences? References?

Comment: What is the item?

Comment: It is called 'FleshEater' from Out of the Abyss. Cursed short sword that gives you barbarian rage while wielding in combat... but the player has no control over who they attack or when they stop combat.

Comment: There’s nothing “implicit” about anyone at tuning - it’s very much explicit

Comment: Not sure i understand your point / reference ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answers are in your quotes.  Only the last sentence about attunement refers to the voluntary process:

> A creature can also voluntarily end attunement by spending another Short Rest focused on the item, unless the item is cursed.

This is reinforced by the sentence under cursed items:

> Attunement to a cursed item can't be ended voluntarily unless the curse is broken 1st such as with the Remove Curse spell.

Neither of those affect the forms of ending attunement involuntarily:

> A creature's attunement to an item ends if the creature no longer satisfies the Prerequisites for attunement, if the item has been more than 100 feet away for at least 24 hours, if the creature dies, or if another creature attunes to the item.

So in this case, Player B can indeed attune to the item if he can get his hands on it, and this does (involuntarily) end the attunement to the item of Player A.

Comment: My thoughts exactly... But I am Player B and no one else in my party supports this theory :(

Comment: @jesses.co.tt Is their argument that Player A is voluntarily allowing Player B to attune and thus end the curse?

Comment: No, they are trying to stay attuned to it so that Player B cannot use it.

Comment: Though I guess that's the counter argument

Comment: That sounds like the definition of involuntary. How did you 'steal' it and stay away from them for 1 hour without them noticing?

Comment: @NautArch among other things?  Wait for them to be asleep.

Comment: It was dropped during a battle, and I picked it up. Relevant?

Comment: Just finding it odd Player A didn't notice he didn't have his item for over an hour.

Comment: There are many ways around that.  That isn't the question.  The issue at hand is: IF B can get his hands on the item for an hour, can he attune to it in place of A?  And the answer to that question is "yes".  HOW he gets his hands on it for an hour is a totally separate question.

Comment: I agree. But how (if?) A lets go of the weapon could have bearing on whether   B gets a chance at it at all.

Comment: Also, B is a woman... :D

Comment: Had a feeling as soon as I typed I should have used neutral. But I asked mostly because I wanted to understand how it happened even though it really isn't relevant to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To my Vouluntary is not part of the question.   If I ask someone to take the weapon and attune it that does not make it vouluntary.   The person who takes the time to attune made that choice them selves.   As long as you can hand it to them asking them to attune doesn't automatially force them with no choice.  Hence, it now attuned to person B.